# Manage notifications settings inside the app on Andorid O and higher

Tags: android, notificationmanager, notification-channel

I've created a few notification channels on my android app using:

```
val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
```

My question now is if it's possible to manage (enable/disable) notifications (and channels) inside the app or if we should always redirect the user to the android settings to manage that?

Examples: Can I completely disable notifications programatically? Can I do that only for a specific channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit a NotificationChannel once it created. It will keep the original configuration, even if you delete the channel and re-create it again (with the same channel id).

In the Settings app, it turns off a specific notification channel by using `INotificationManager.updateNotificationChannelGroupForPackage`, which is a hidden API.

Therefore, the only way to manage notifications is always to redirect users to the Settings page.